# Help on Research Proposal

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am a freshman majoring in chemistry. I am aware that one of the tasks required in this field is extensive research, and I am encountering a big problem. I am lost as to how to think of a plausible paper— I am not sure how to think of proper "topics" that would suffice the requirement in this field. I am once advised to look for societal problems and how my field can potentially propose solutions to it, but as of now, I'm still blank to any topics and/or ideas. I hope any of the people here can guide me through this so that once that I'm actually assigned to write, I can think of a topic without any problems.

Comment: A few suggestions: antibiotic resistant pathogenic bacteria, carbon capture technology, fossil fuel replacements, novel antivirals, the impact of CRISPR techonlogy on genetic manipulation.

Comment: Perhaps this reference will give you some ideas to explore, see Zou, P.; Leddy, J., 'Magnetized Nickel Electrodes for Improved Charge and Discharge Rates in Nickel Metal Hydride and Nickel Cadmium Batteries', Electrochemical and Solid-State Letters 2006, 9, A43-A45. To quote: "magnetized electrodes yielded higher currents than the corresponding nonmagnetic electrodes by 70 and 230 %, respectively." at https://www.electrochem.org/dl/ma/206/pdfs/0541.pdf .

Comment: You're posing a question that many advanced graduate students have trouble answering...